# How can I export a Vue.js v-data-table to excel spreadsheet?

Tags: vue.js, export-to-excel

I am new to Vue.js. I need to figure out how to export v-data-table content to an excel spreadsheet on a button click on the client side. What is the simplest way to accomlpish this?